# Windows 10 Picture Viewer keeps hiding top of images with toolbar

Tags: windows-10, pictures

In this very annoying issue (feature?), the Picture Viewer shows the toolbar as soon as I open a large height image, making it difficult to see the area that gets covered.

Is there a way to make the toolbar fixed without being on top of images, or keep it hidden at all times?

[image]

Comment: Spacebar hides the toolbar [link](http://winaero.com/blog/the-list-of-keyboard-shortcuts-for-photos-app-in-windows-10/)

Comment: @spike_66 thanks spike that really helps. could potentially be a good answer for my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and accepted the comment from @spike_66 as a resolution

*Spacebar hides the toolbar [link](http://winaero.com/blog/the-list-of-keyboard-shortcuts-for-photos-app-in-windows-10/)*